# d3.selectAll get the style fill value of map's path

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to get the colour from the path but it gives me initially assigned colour. Initially, I filled the whole path with yellow colour(see below code):

***# Line 566:***

```
  india.selectAll("path")
    .data(fixed)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", "#ffffd9")
```

but using the following code I assigned them diff. colour based on value:

***# Line 620:***

```
  india.selectAll("path").transition().duration(1000)
    .style("fill", function (d) { 
      // log("=======>",d, d.confirmed);
      return colormap(d.properties.confirmed); });
```

This is what I have tried:

***# Line 642:***

```
   rects = india.selectAll('path');
    // clear previous selection
    // rects.style({'stroke': 'none', 'stroke-width': '1px'});
    // loop and hightlight matches
    rects.each(function(){
      var r = d3.select(this);
      log("-----======--------", r._groups[0][0]);
      log("!!!!!!!!!:",r._groups[0][0].style.cssText);
      log("-->==>",r._groups[0][0].path);
      log("#####:", r.style('fill'), hexToRGB('#fdedec'));
      log("@@@@@@:", (r.style('fill')===hexToRGB('#fdedec')));

      // if (r.style('fill') === self.style('fill')){
      //   r.style({'stroke': 'red', 'stroke-width': '2px'});
      });
```

But it gives me initially assigned colour(yellow), not the changed ones(shades of red). How to do it?

**Code + demo:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/4tsSOBuNhi418Pt5?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: On a side note, looks like you are trying to access the node but  `d3.select(this)._groups[0][0] == this`. What do you get if you don't use a transition (removing `.transition().duration()`), right now you check the color right away, not at the end of the transition.

Comment: Sorry, not a [dc.js] question... It's a bit harder to get answers on D3, partly because every D3 code is unique.